# SSH with PAM Google

Tags: server, ssh, pam

I have a server with Google Authenticator enabled. It worked fine, and one day I tried to login, and suddenly I'm not able to.

Fortunately, I do have Ajenti installed with a terminal, so it's not a huge deal, but I need to connect to the server from multiple devices, and I no longer can do that with anyone of them.

As far as the error, I get a "Connection Refused" Which is odd, because it worked fine before. Now, I am a novice, so go easy on me if I'm doing something stupid, but having done everything I could I'm stumped.

Error log : 
https://bitbucket.org/snippets/keyxmakerx/4Bgq

Comment: Have you checked the times on your server and client devices? Google authenticator only works fine if the times are in sync.

Comment: Yes, Time is correct, but it isn't even asking me for the Auth Code, it just immediately says connection refused.

Comment: From your log file I see several problems: 1. `error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key` is the key there? Do you need this key (else remove it from `sshd_config`). 2. `(pam_google_authenticator)[358]: Invalid verification code` and 3. `error: PAM: Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session for nonadmin from 162.17.78.154`. Please ort out this problems one after another, starting with the missing server key.

Comment: I have fixed those issues by reinstalling the PAM, and removing that key. (Odd, I do not know where that key came from) But i still can't login, and I do not have any logs as to why either.

Comment: If you get 'connection refused' before the password prompt, it looks like a problem with sshd itself... Check SSH is running with 'ps aux | grep sshd'. Also check you can do 'ssh localhost' from inside the machine. Also check there's no firewall or missing port forward that could block the connection (SSH is TCP port 22)

Comment: SSh on my machine is port 2892

Comment: root@SHARED1:/# ps aux | grep sshd                                                                                                                              root     19903  0.0  0.0  11740   932 pts/3    S+   06:21   0:00 grep --color=auto sshd

Comment: Groups for nonadmin - nonadmin : nonadmin root sudo www-data ssh

Comment: Tried to remote in, failed ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 2892: Connection refused